# How do I use Pester to test for both an error and a wrong value?

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm trying to test if certain sites has been blocked succesfully for a client using Pester v4.
But I can't figure out how to mark two failed attempts as one single success test.

I'd like to combine two following failure tests in to one

```
$PrivacyBlackList = @('nexusrules.live.com', 'auc-visio-telemetry.officeapps.live.com')

Describe '- Check MS Telemetry Compliance' {

  Context '- Get Windows and Office Telemetry' {

    foreach ($BlackSite in $PrivacyBlackList) {

      It "Should not succesfully connect to $BlackSite" {
        $ConnectTest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3
        $ConnectTest.StatusCode | Should -Not -Be '200'
      }

      It "Should timeout connecting to $BlackSite" {
        {$ConnectTest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3} |
          Should -Throw 'The operation has timed out.'
      }

    }# end foreach
  }
}
```

```
Describing - Check MS Telemetry Compliance

  Context - Get Windows and Office Telemetry
    [-] Should not succesfully connect to nexusrules.live.com 3.23s
      WebException: The operation has timed out.
    [+] Should timeout connecting to nexusrules.live.com 3.23s
    [-] Should not succesfully connect to auc-visio-telemetry.officeapps.live.com 2s
      Expected '200' to be different from the actual value, but got the same value.
      9:         $ConnectTest.StatusCode | Should -Not -Be '200'
    [-] Should timeout connecting to auc-visio-telemetry.officeapps.live.com 1.19s
      Expected an exception, with message 'The operation has timed out.' to be thrown, 
      but no exception was thrown.
      14:           Should -Throw 'The operation has timed out.'
```

Pester has no "`-Be -Or`"...

Edit 1: @mklement0 pointed out that in my simplifed example (now removed) `Should -BeIn` will solve the simplified example.

Edit 2: Changed simplified example (now removed) to be more in line with my real issue

Edit 3: Changing simplified example (now removed) to do errors :)

Comment: At least in Pester 5, `Should` has `-BeIn`:  `8..9 | Should -BeIn 8, 9` (not sure about v4)

Comment: Great, `Should -BeIn` works with Pester v4 :). But that doesn't handle my real issue where I seemingly need two checks for one result :/

Comment: You can put 2 `Should` statements in a single `It` block if that's your question. If one fails, the whole `It` fails.

Comment: It's the other way around, I need one to fail to be succesful...

Comment: I mean, I think it is clear, a failed test is a failed test. A statement that doesn't result in what it `Should` be.

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you are getting at...

Comment: But the simplified example are throwing us of the subject I'm afraid :/ I'll just remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that `Invoke-WebRequest` returns a non-terminating error when it can't connect to a URL, which is why your test is failing.

You can deal with the error by wrapping the call to `Invoke-WebRequest` in a `try`..`catch` (no need to do anything in the `catch` block):

```
$PrivacyBlackList = @('nexusrules.live.com', 'auc-visio-telemetry.officeapps.live.com')

Describe '- Check MS Telemetry Compliance' {

  Context '- Get Windows and Office Telemetry' {

    foreach ($BlackSite in $PrivacyBlackList) {

      It "Should not succesfully connect to $BlackSite" {
        try { $ConnectTest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop } catch {}
        $ConnectTest.StatusCode | Should -Not -Be '200'
      }

      It "Should timeout connecting to $BlackSite" {
        {$ConnectTest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3} |
          Should -Throw 'The operation has timed out.'
      }

    }# end foreach
  }
}
```

As Santiago Squarzon said, if you want both checks to be a single test you can combine them into a single `It`:

```
    It "Should timeout connecting to $BlackSite and not return 200" {
        {$ConnectTest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3} | Should -Throw 'The operation has timed out.'
        $ConnectTest.StatusCode | Should -Not -Be '200'
      }
```

Edit: If you want to make a second check conditional on the outcome of the first, perhaps you could do something like this:

```
It "Should not succesfully connect to $BlackSite" {
    try { $ConnectTest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop } catch {}
    $ConnectTest.StatusCode | Should -Not -Be '200'

    if (-not $ConnectTest.StatusCode) {
        { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3 } | Should -Throw 'The operation has timed out.'
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I get something else then '200' there was NO terminating error... You've provided an AND clause. I need a clause where only one `Should` is enough.

Comment: I'm confused on what value the second test gives you at all. You want the result to either be a timeout, or a non 200 result. The first test in my example above should now handle that.

Comment: @Dennis if you have 2 `Should` statements in the `It` block, if the first one fails then the 2nd one will just not run. Mark's answer is correct here.

Comment: All `Should` within one `It` has to be successful for the `It` clause to be successful, right?

Comment: @Dennis yes.... try `Context 'Testing' { It 'should stop @ first test' { 1 | Should -Be 2; sleep -second 60 | Should -BeNullOrEmpty } }`

Comment: If the second `Should`is successful (where a value such as 404 is forcefully returned by an upstream proxy) in the example above, the test for terminating error will fail.

Comment: See the edited addition at the end of my answer. Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's it :) I actually tried that out myself just now.

Comment: Good points, but it seems that `Invoke-WebRequest` _does_ report a (statement-)terminating error by default, in both PowerShell editions. E.g, `try { iwr https://localhost:21 } catch { 'NO!' }` (in this example, the error is refusal to connect, but it seems to behave the same with an unknown host name or even a 404 status).

Comment: Ah, but will it affect the test? If a call returns both 404 AND terminates, then I don't need to try for a terminating error?

Comment: @Dennis: There is no output if a statement-terminating error occurs, including due to a 404 status. (The only exceptional case I am aware of - in Windows PowerShell only - is when a 302 status is reported,  in which case output _is_ produced, accompanied by a _non-terminating_ error).

Comment: Yes, then i will get $null or '302' which isn't '200' :)

Comment: Good point; you can therefore simplify to `$(try { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlackSite -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3).StatusCode } catch {}) | Should -Not -Be 200` - this also avoids the pitfall of assigning to a variable _inside the `try` block_, as that results in _no_ assignment being performed in case of a terminating error, which could accidentally surface a _preexisting_ value. That said, you can solve that problem by moving the assignment out of the block; that is, use
`$foo = try { 1 / 0 } catch {}` instead of `try { $foo = 1 / 0 } catch {}`